# How to perform a LINQ join on IQueryable<T> from two different database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a WebAPI method which uses the OData Query Options to return data to the client. The method is used to get the entity 'WHTRatesMaster' records. The entity has 'Country' as one of its properties(It's actually the country code and not the name). Country names are available separately from another entity CountryCodes which lies in a database different from the WHTRatesMaster DB. In order to return the new property for country name, I have created a new class named 'WHTRatesMasterDTO'. Below is my code:

```
public class WHTRatesMaster
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

public class WHTRatesMasterDTO
{
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
    public string CountryIsoCode { get; set; }
}

public class CountryCodes
{
    public string Iso3CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

[HttpGet]
[Route("api/WHTRatesMaster")]
public PageResult<WHTRatesMasterDTO> GetWHTRatesMasterDbSet(ODataQueryOptions options)
{
    var whtRatesDTOList = from whtRatesItem in aqrOperationsDbCtx.WHTRatesMasterDbSet
                         join country in secMasterDbCtx.CountryCodesDbSet on whtRatesItem.Country equals country.Iso3CountryCode
                         select new WHTRatesMasterDTO()
                         {
                             CountryName = whtRatesItem.Country,
                             CountryIsoCode = country.Country,
                         };

            var whtRatesMasterPageData = options.ApplyTo(whtRatesDTOList) as IQueryable<WHTRatesMaster>;

            var odataProperties = Request.ODataProperties();

            return new PageResult<WHTRatesMasterDTO>(whtRatesDTOList, odataProperties.NextLink, odataProperties.TotalCount);
}
```

When I execute the above code I get the following exception message: "**The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.**"

Could I get some help in finding a solution to the problem.

**UPDATE:**
I have also tried to get the country list in memory and then join it with the IQueryable. But this too didn't work for me.

Comment: You join on whtRatesItem.Country equals country.Iso3CountryCode and then select both of these properties (which are equal). What's the point?

Comment: Oops...sorry, my mistake...I should have taken that as country.Country

Answer (score 1):

You're going to change IQueryable results to something like IList.  The join won't work across objects backed by two completely unrelated 'virtual' list providers.

```
var whtRatesDTOList = from whtRatesItem in aqrOperationsDbCtx.WHTRatesMasterDbSet.ToList()
                     join country in secMasterDbCtx.CountryCodesDbSet.ToList() on whtRatesItem.Country equals country.Iso3CountryCode
                     select new WHTRatesMasterDTO()
                     {
                         CountryName = whtRatesItem.Country,
                         CountryIsoCode = country.Iso3CountryCode,
                         };
```

Unfortunately, this will pull the whole result set from both sides into memory, and THEN evaluate the join.  You might need to tune the code.

Comment: You could get two different queries (using toList()) and after that use a join.

Comment: Don't think this would be a good idea. The WHTRatesMasterDbSet has too many records to play with in the memory. I also have to apply the OData Query Options on WHTRatesMaster.

Comment: Then do .ToList on the other data source (CountryCodesDbSet), get the key values, and then narrow your query on WHTRatesMasterDbSet by having it do an 'in' query on those key values.